# What are the differences between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

I've got two options for unicode that look promising for a mysql database.

```
utf8_general_ci unicode (multilingual), case-insensitive
utf8_unicode_ci unicode (multilingual), case-insensitive
```

Can you please explain what is the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci? What are the effects of choosing one over the other when designing a database?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`utf8_general_ci` is a very simple — and on Unicode, very broken — collation, one that gives **incorrect results** on general Unicode text.  What it does is:

- converts to Unicode normalization form D for canonical decomposition
- removes any combining characters
- converts  to upper case

This does not work correctly on Unicode, because it does not understand Unicode casing. Unicode casing alone is much more complicated than an ASCII-minded approach can handle. For example:

- The lowercase of “ẞ” is “ß”, but the uppercase of “ß” is “SS”.
- There are two lowercase Greek sigmas, but only one uppercase one; consider “Σίσυφος”.
- Letters like “ø” do not decompose to an “o” plus a diacritic, meaning that it won’t correctly sort.

There are many other subtleties.

1. `utf8_unicode_ci` uses the standard [***Unicode Collation Algorithm***](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/), supports so called expansions and ligatures, for example: 
   German letter ß (U+00DF LETTER SHARP S) is sorted near "ss" 
   Letter Œ (U+0152 LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE) is sorted near "OE".

`utf8_general_ci` does not support expansions/ligatures, it sorts 
all these letters as single characters, and sometimes in a wrong order.

2. `utf8_unicode_ci` is *generally* more accurate for all scripts. 
   For example, on Cyrillic block: 
   `utf8_unicode_ci` is fine for all these languages: 
   Russian, Bulgarian, Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, and Ukrainian. 
   While utf8_general_ci is fine only for Russian and Bulgarian subset of Cyrillic. 
   Extra letters used in Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, and Ukrainian 
   are sorted not well.

The cost of `utf8_unicode_ci` is that it is a *little* bit 
slower than `utf8_general_ci`. But that’s the price you pay for correctness. Either you can have a fast answer that’s wrong, or a very slightly slower answer that’s right. Your choice.
 It is very difficult to ever justify giving wrong answers, so it’s best to assume that `utf8_general_ci` doesn’t exist and to always use `utf8_unicode_ci`. Well, unless you want wrong answers.

Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748#msg-188748

Comment: Props for the list of languages

Comment: Looks like this answer was straight copied from the mysql forum http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748#msg-188748

Comment: @Matt: well, some of us search on google :P

Comment: doesn't stop you from quoting the original source when you copy / paste an answer :P

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `utf8_general_ci` over `utf8_unicode_ci`, then?

Comment: Never use `utf8_general_ci` [http://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/570763](http://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/570763)

Comment: @GnomeSlice, it's a _leeeeetle_ bit faster.

Comment: if `utf8_general_ci` is so bad, why does the MySQL driver use it [by default](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#unicode-support) in `go`

Answer (score 21):

From [Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#id743026) in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/):

> For any Unicode character set, operations performed using the `_general_ci` collation are faster than those for the `_unicode_ci` collation. For example, comparisons for the `utf8_general_ci` collation are faster, but slightly less correct, than comparisons for `utf8_unicode_ci`. The reason for this is that `utf8_unicode_ci` supports mappings such as expansions; that is, when one character compares as equal to combinations of other characters. For example, in German and some other languages “`ß`” is equal to “`ss`”. `utf8_unicode_ci` also supports contractions and ignorable characters. `utf8_general_ci` is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters. It can make only one-to-one comparisons between characters.