# How to properly display non-redable characters stored in a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have `São Tomé and Príncipe` stored in a MySQL database.

It displays on my web page as `S�o Tom� and Pr�ncipe`

Is there anyway to display it properly straight from the database?

My MySQL Type is `MyISAM` and the collation is `utf8_general_ci`

My web page charset is `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Field type is set to `varchar(30)` and field collations is same as table `utf8_general_ci`

**PHP FUNCTION TESTS**

`utf8_decode()` converted characters to `S?o Tom? and Pr?ncipe`
`htmlspecialchars_decode()` converted characters to `S�o Tom� and Pr�ncipe`
`html_entity_decode()` converted characters to `S�o Tom� and Pr�ncipe`
`quoted_printable_decode()` converted characters to `S�o Tom� and Pr�ncipe`
`htmlentities()` returned blank result

**GOT IT TO WORK THANKS TO @SAEVEN**

Ran this right before my query SELECT

`mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_link'], "SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Comment: What is your encoding type set as?

Comment: See also [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: see my amended question @Fred

Comment: @H.Ferrence thanks, I saw it just now. Only other thing that comes to mind is the infamous/notorious "BOM".

Comment: What is the field type set as ? varchar, text, blob .. ?

Comment: see amended question @SajjadMerchant

Comment: Is/are your file(s) set `with` or `without` the BOM? I've answered quite a few questions relative to yours.

Comment: umm, not sure what "BOM" means...sorry @Fred

Comment: It's the `byte order mark` see the Wiki on the subject > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark - I have a client's website that just hates not having it.

Comment: Yeah, I just googled it. how do I detect the byte order mark? @Fred

Comment: Get a copy of Notepad++ > http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ - open the file in question then under `Encoding`, it will show you what it is set at. You then go to `Encoding` again, then either convert to `UTF-8 without BOM` or `Convert to UTF-8`. One of which may solve your problem. It has for me, many times.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll get a copy of notepad++ someday. Seems like a lot of work to get to displaying the data properly -- I mean, downloading/installing and trying to learn note++. For now, I guess my issue is not that critical to solve. Thanks for helping @Fred.

Comment: You're welcome, worth a shot though. Have a look at this on SO, might be of help > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052982/accented-characters-stored-in-mysql-database?rq=1

Comment: Well, I have many non-readable chars in that table. I was hoping to find some php decode function or something like that. I'll just live with the issue for now. Thanks again @Fred

Comment: Have you consulted the PHP manual on the subject? > http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I goggled decoding...then came here. The php manual is not always easy to use to get solutions. I know there are a few encode() and decode() functions. I was hoping someone might have had this issue and solved it. I am going to to go the link you provided above and see if that helps me. Thanks again @Fred

Comment: Anytime @H.Ferrence - sorry I couldn't be of more help. That's about the scope of my knowledge (for now). I'll give it an `upvote`, see if anyone else picks up on it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you need to specify your namespace collation at the connection level?

I assume that you've covered the basics, you've got the charset as utf8 in your HTML markup.

Try executing this SQL statement before you do any of your database queries:

'SET NAMES utf8'

e.g., if you are using PDO

```
// do your regular connection logic whatever it is
$dbc = new PDO( .... );
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbc->query( 'SET NAMES utf8' );

// run your queries beneath
....
```

or can use the shorthand

```
new PDO(
    'mysql:host=mysql.example.com;dbname=awesome_db',
    "username",
    "password",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

Whatever DBAL you use, that query'll work.  Just run it on the same connection you use to pull your data, before pulling it (only needs to be done once)

Comment: thanks @saeven - you helped me solve my issue. I amended my question with the solution I used (I code procedurally)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Common problem that can be pretty obscure unless you've banged your head against a wall over it before. ;)  Thanks for the vote!