# imap_fetchbody not show special characters

Tags: php, imap

I use imap_fetchbody to download email from my personal email to a MYSQL DB and when i use with special characters, like accents, in my DB save n? instead of nº for example

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Example:

```
$data = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$mid,'0');
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a MySQL issue than an IMAP issue.

Try [encoding the data as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052982/accented-characters-stored-in-mysql-database). You may also need to [specify the character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html) used by the tables in your database.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert like this `$data = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($mbox,$mid,'0'));`
before the db insertion.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php