# Using str_split on a UTF-8 encoded string

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I'm currently working on a project, and instead of using regular MySQL queries I thought I'd go ahead and learn how to use PDO.

I have a table called contestants, both the database, the table, and all of the columns are in utf-8. I have ten entries in the contestant table, and their column "name" contains characters such as åäö.

Now, when I fetch an entry from the database, and var_dump the name, I get a good result, a string with all the special characters intact. But what I need to do is to split the string by characters, to get them in an array that I then shuffle.

For instance, I have this string:
**Test ÅÄÖ Tåän**

And when I run str_split I get each character in it's own key in an array. The only issue is that all the special characters display as this: �, meaning the array will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => T
    [1] => e
    [2] => s
    [3] => t
    [4] =>  
    [5] => �
    [6] => �
    [7] => �
    [8] => �
    [9] => �
    [10] => �
    [11] =>  
    [12] => T
    [13] => �
    [14] => �
    [15] => �
    [16] => �
    [17] => n
)
```

As you can see, it not only messes up the characters, but it also duplicates them in str_split process. I've tried several ways to split the string, but they all have the same issue. When I output the string before the split, it shows the special characters just fine.

This is my dbConn.php code:

// Require config file:
    require_once('config.inc.php');

```
// Start PDO connection:
$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbHandle -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

// Set error reporting:
$dbHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

And this is the code that I use to fetch from the database and loop:

```
// Require files:
require_once('dbConn.php');

// Get random artist:
$artist = $dbHandle->query("SELECT * FROM ".ARTIST_TABLE." WHERE id = 11 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$artist->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$artist = $artist->fetch();
var_dump($artist->name);

// Split name:
$artistChars = str_split($artist->name);
```

I'm connecting with utf-8, my php file is utf-8 **without BOM** and no other special characters on this page share this issue. What could be wrong, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be charset=utf8 in the PDO part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) does not work with multi-byte characters, it will only return the first byte - thus invalidating your characters. you could use [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

Comment: I did try to use mb_split now that you told me, and it seemed to work, although I could not find a proper regexp so I ended up using preg_split.

$artistChars = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $artist->name);

Although, now I need to make all the characters lowercase, and mb_convert_case messes up the characters as well..

Comment: @Jonathan, you can try the `mb_ereg()` function, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php

Answer (score 152):

Mind that the utf8 declaration used in your connect-string is reported to be not working.
In the comments on php.net I frequently see this alternative:

```
$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

Comment: +1, I had a similar issue where an ü in the database was being displayed as a � in php. Adding that additional parameter to my PDO connection fixed the issue.

Comment: +1, it took me 4 hours to finally find what was causing the problem. After using the exact connection script from the PHP manual example, how that could possibly be the problem? I'm so mad at the PHP development team right now...

Comment: Oh thank you so very much for this reply.  A million "thank you"s and more.

Comment: Had a similar issue (no string splitting) where results had � between characters. This fixed it.

Comment: Luckily I found this answer directly, saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: +1 for , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"), you saved my life

Answer (score 10):

**UTF-8 Using PDO**

problems when writing international (even Chinese and Thailandic) characters to the database

there may be more ways to make this work. I am not an expert, just a tech-freak, interested to understand all this. In Linux and Windows  I have set up a few CMS (content-managing-systems), using a sample from the following website:

'http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql'

The sample is using PDO for insert, update and delete.

It took me a few hours to find a solution. Whatever I did, I always concluded differences between the data in my forms and in the phpmyadmin/heidi -views

I followed the hints of: 'https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4' but there was still no success

In my CMS-structure there is a file 'Config.php':
After reading this webpage I changed the line

```
    define( 'DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mythings);
```

to

```
    define( 'DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mythings;charset=utf8');
```

Now all works fine.

Comment: That did the trick! In my very humble pretending opinion, this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `str_split` function splits by byte, not by character.  You'll need [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

Comment: Thanks :)
I ended up using preg_split like this: $artistChars = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $artist->name); Although, now I need to make all the characters lowercase, and mb_convert_case messes up the characters as well..

Answer (score 3):

this work for me... hope its usefull.

ensure that the database, apache and every config was in utf8.

PDO OBJECT

```
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') . ';dbname=' . config::read('db.basename') .';charset=utf8'. ';port=' . Config::read('db.port') .';connect_timeout=15';
            $user = Config::read('db.user');
            $password = Config::read('db.password');
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

it work if not using another function like str_word_count.

USING str_word_count you need to use utf8_decode(utf8_encode)..

```
function cortar($str)
{
    if (20>$count=str_word_count($str)) {
        return $str;
    }
    else
    {
        $array = str_word_count($str,1,'.,-0123456789()+=?¿!"<>*ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ@|/%$#¡');
        $s='';
        $c=0;
        foreach ($array as $e) {
            if (20>$c) {
                if (19>$c) {
                $s.=$e.' ';
                }
                else
                {
                $s.=$e;
                }               
            }
            $c+=1;
        }
        return utf8_decode(utf8_encode($s));
    }
}
```

function returs string with 20 words.

Answer (score 3):

## UTF-8 PROBLEMS & SOLUTIONS by PHP FUNCTIONS

**1. How to Save UTF-8 Charterers (mathematical string,special chars like 92 ÷ 8 ÷ 2 = ? ) ?**

Ans.  **$string =utf8_encode('92 ÷ 8 ÷ 2 = ?');**

**2. How to print UTF-8 Charterers From Database ?**

Ans. **echo utf8_decode($string);**

Note: If you do not want to do this by using encoding/decoding you can do this via.

## 1. if you are using mysqli_query() then

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','db_username','password','your_database_name');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

## 2.If you are using PDO then

```
class Database extends PDO{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name","gurutslz_root","Your_db_password",array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
    }
}
$conn=new Database();
```

Answer (score 0):

I only had issues with text fields in my database structure, storing product descriptions. I set the field settings to blob instead of text, which solved my problem.