# php turns string quotes to question mark

Tags: php, pdo, insert

Im using php PDO and trying to insert into the DB a string in hebrew that contains quotas.
It inserts the text but  keeps turning the quotes('/"/`) to question marks, how can I fix that ?

the code im using:

```
$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'hebrew'");
         $this->db->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
         $this->db->query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
         $this->db->query("set collation_connection='utf8'");

        $createQuery = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO X(Y)VALUES (:name");
        //$_POST['string'] = זאת' "בדיקה"
        $createQuery->bindParam("name",$_POST['string']);

        $createQuery->execute();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea; no code makes it that much more harder to tell.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can only assume it's an encoding issue.

Comment: please, post your queries

Comment: Forgot to add the code, edited.

Comment: The `?` characters are displaying in your browser output? You may have the wrong output encoding.  See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) to make sure you have all the pieces in place.

Comment: please provide sample input - or even better, get rid of `$_POST`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the ? are displayed in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822461/pdo-utf-8-character-issue Hope it helps