# Can't show json object in case of german umlauts

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have simple function that do this:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, birthDate, address, phoneNumber, housingSituation1 FROM client WHERE id = ?");

    $param = 2;
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $param);
    $stmt->execute();

    $obj = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();

    echo json_encode($obj);
```

This worked good until at one point i noticed its not returning anything but i get status 200 from that function, when i started debugging i seen that i have client with lastName: **M*ü*ller**, so after i repleaced ü with u that script started working again. 
Then i googled a bit and found that i can use something like this echo `json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`but its not working for me.
Anyone knows how i can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602075/problems-with-german-umlauts-in-php-json-encode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41692298/6369494 check this for PDO.

Comment: I faced same problem with Arabic language.

Comment: I seen that, but as you can see i;m using get_result()->fetch_object() feature of mysqlnd driver, and since my client table have ~70 attributes i dont want to bind every attribute one by one, do you know how i can apply  solution from there to mine example ?

Comment: You have 2 options either configure your database with UTF-8 or you write the code while connection of database.

Comment: You will get result but cant pass to the operative functions

Comment: I solved my issue thanks to links that you guys provided, i posted answer and it works great!
@TejasMehta how to properly set database with UTF-8, i already on my every table have this 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue like this, on my dbConnect php file i added **mysqli_set_charset**, and my dbConnect.php looks like this. I hope this helps someone.

```
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'local_db';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
```

Comment: Great.. Get beer and chill