# Convert characters pasted from Word in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a real nightmare parsing data from one database where much of the text has been pasted from Word across into another database. The data needs to be washed through the parser each day so it isn't just a matter of cleaning up the source data once.

The trouble is that the target keeps moving as it gets processed and I'm getting very mixed results.

The process basically is to copy exported SQL generated from PHPMyAdmin; paste this into a form and then run the parsing script; the script then saves the 'cleaned' data into a different database.

A sample of what is in the data includes stuff like...

```
Comply with â€œRegulationsâ€?
```

Where ideally this would be...

```
Comply with "Regulations"
```

By the time all the parsing is done and stored in the new database I'm left with...

```
Comply with AS3868 Ã¢â‚¬Å"RegulationsÃ¢â‚¬Â
```

There are other Word characters such as elipsis etc but this example just shows the smart-quotes.

What is the best way for me to clean the data once it is posted through via a form?

Comment: see `mysql_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: I think that this just escapes characters for SQL. I need to replace the offending code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one ended up being much more of a pain to solve than it sounds as though it should have been. Essentially the data was corrupting through various processes where there wasn't a clearly defined encoding environment. Essentially the data was double-encoding as it was parsed so that **“** became **â€œ** and then became **Ã¢â‚¬Å“**

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding) helped enormously with understanding the environmental issues and how to make sure PHP, MySQL and my coding environment were all using UTF-8 as its defaults.

[This site](http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/) was great with testing and fixing the mysql environment. The code from that page worked well on the server (accessed and changed using SSL). I use a WAMP server locally and the code didn't work well there. I ended up making the following changes to my my.ini file

```
[client]
...
default-character-set=utf8

[wampmysqld]
...
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

Then I needed to fix the data that was there.

I was going to just replace the offending code with safe single-byte characters (**“** would be **"**) but in the end I decided to just make sure the multi-byte characters were corrected so that they displayed when viewed as UTF-8.

I didn't want to trust a script to encode the search and replace strings and I found a great starting point [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,420270,420772). I used MySQL's UNHEX function to control this aspect:

```
-- Single quotes
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACCB9C'), UNHEX('E28098'));
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACE284A2'), UNHEX('E28099'));
-- Double quotes
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACC593'), UNHEX('E2809C'));
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACC29D'), UNHEX('E2809D'));
-- Em and En dashes
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACE2809C'), UNHEX('E28094'));
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('C3A2E282ACE2809D'), UNHEX('E28094'));
```

To make sure everything was working, I took a copy of the table and then replaced all of the changed multi-byte characters to single characters

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E28098'), "'");
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E28099'), "'");
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E2809C'), '"');
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E2809D'), '"');
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E28093'), '-');
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, UNHEX('E28094'), '-');
```

and then ran this MySQL script to capture any records that still contained multi-byte characters:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(column) != CHAR_LENGTH(column);
```

This was I was able to quickly hunt down the anomalies in the existing data.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to transfer data across different systems.