# Loop through MySQL database changing apostrophes with UTF-8 version

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've been having some trouble with my website + database, the content was added to the database using a java app using some unknown charset and they are being displayed in PHP/HTML using UTF-8 `<meta charset='UTF-8'>` but im getting a bunch of diamond shaped question marks.

I've tried changing the charsets around and using the htmlentities function but i'm not having much luck. I was wondering if its possible to loop through a database table removing all instances of some character (old apostrophes) and replacing it with the utf-8 (apostrophes) version?

I've also set the database charset to utf-8. It's just this old content i'm having trouble with.

Old apostrophe: ’

Desired apostrophe: '

Comment: those aren't commas, those are apostrophes. Commas are `,`

Comment: @ElefantPhace as you can see this stuff is making me lose my mind too :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a query for each table, like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = replace(field1, "’", "'"),
field2 = replace(field2, "’", "'")
etc.
```

Comment: Sounds good.  I couldn't test it, so you might need to escape the single quote differently than I posted above.  For example it might be replace(field1, '’', '''') or replace(field1, '’', '\'') if the double quotes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The old content was added to the database using a non UTF8 charset and thats why its showing up as  �. Unfortunately a thorough fix wont be possible as all symbols don't transliterate well to UTF8. You might want to simply Update the ones that you find like the apostropes `’` . You might also find useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding)

Edit: The update i mentioned would be like Ben's query