# Can't get rid of diamonds with question marks in the middle since php 5.6 switch

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Rackspace upgraded their servers to php 5.6/apache 2.4 and ever since then, I have had several sites show these strange characters.  I have gone all through google to apply patches/fixes but absolutely nothing is working.  Here is an example of one:  believerschallenge.com/index.php

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Character encoding default has probably changed

Comment: Your database (or part of it) is encoded in latin1 but the page is displayed as utf8. Your webpages doesn't have encoding definition. Try to put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" >` in html header. If iso-8859-1 isn't ok, look at the encoding of your tables

Comment: Had the same problem with a site that was copied to another server by the provider. They used some method that converted the files from utf8 to ascii, so all non-latin characters became corrupt. You may need to manually fix them after you ensure that the files on the server are in the correct format

Answer (score 0):

While it's not immediately obvious what character those are supposed to be, I can think of two ways to try to address this. The first is to check the source where these characters are appearing and remove / alter the characters that aren't being rendered correctly.

The second is more complicated but probably better in the long run, and it involves checking the various things detailed in this question: 
[I need help fixing Broken UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding)

In particular, this one is probably the cause:

Change your PHP default charset to utf-8:
`ini_set("default_charset", 'utf-8');`

Answer (score 0):

See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#)

You probably have latin1-encoded bytes in your text and have not specified that the connection between the client and the server is utf8.  Both should be changed to get rid of the black-diamond-with-question-mark.