# database issue with arabic encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, arabic, iconv

I have a wordpress website and for some reason all records values that are in Arabic language change to be like this `Ù…ÙˆÙ‚Ø¹ Ø§Ù„Ø·Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ù†ÙØ³ÙŠ` although the database and it's tables collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.To fix this issue i have decided to make script to select all records from each table and then `iconv` each value to be for example something like this `عنوان باللغة العربية`.

Now the problem i have tried everything and it's not working for me

```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$sql['host']        = "localhost";
$sql['username']    = "root";
$sql['password']    = "";
$sql['database']    = "nafsynet_database";

$connection = mysqli_connect($sql['host'], $sql['username'], $sql['password'], $sql['database']);

if (!$connection) {
    $out .= "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    $out .= "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    $out .= "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;

    echo $out;

    die();
}

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM `nfsy_options` WHERE 1 LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$rows   = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $text =  $row['option_value'];

    echo iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8',$text);echo'<br>';
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: change your db all table column `collation` to `utf-8-bin`. Also you can use `utf-8-bin` encoding in your php code too.

Comment: For debugging purposes please insert `$result = $connection->query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_%'") or die($connection->error);
foreach( $result as $row ) {
 echo join(': ', $row), "<br />\r\n";
} die;` right before `$sql = `, run the script and [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34923472/edit) the output to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to specify utf8 charset for your database connection, by calling [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($sql['host'], $sql['username'], $sql['password'], $sql['database']);

if (!$connection) {
    // ..
}

mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM `nfsy_options` WHERE 1 LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if that is the problem, you probably already have data in your database that has been interpreted with the wrong encoding. In that case you can/should convert the existing data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-conversion.html

Comment: If the contents are broken directly in database, unfortunately changing the column collation wouldn't help, as OP already said the collation is utf8.

For that it is needed to force an encoding change directly in db on the string, something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2379380/5660122

Comment: A CONVERT to latin1 followed by MODIFY to utf8 should do the trick - though I've never tried that.

Comment: Thanks man this solution worked for me i just wanted to share it with you

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = convert(cast(convert(option_value using latin1) as binary) using utf8) where option_id = 3`