# i have problem with arabic content in php page

Tags: php, html, database

this is the sql code:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['newscontent'] . "</td>";
```

this is the other sql code:`

```
echo "<td>" . $row['newstitle'] . "</td>";
```

this is the header:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

i get question marks in the website

I've tried all the solutions but didn't find a solution to my problem

Comment: That is PHP, not SQL. Add db connection data please and what `newscontent` or `newstitle` contain in db and what their data type is.

Comment: Please provide a more complete snippet if possible, how are you interacting with the database? have you ensured that the content was originally stored correctly in the database?

Comment: Your issue is probably with utf_8. [Check if the answers here fix your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923472/database-issue-with-arabic-encoding)