# Wrong utf8 encoding exporting Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I always seen  in phpmyadmin special characters encoded like:
`Ù…ÛŒØ«Ù… Ø§Ø¨Ø±Ø§Ù‡ÛŒÙ…ÛŒØ¬ØØ¹Ø´Ù‚ ØŒ Ø³Ø± Ø¨ Ø±Ø§Ù‡ ØŒ Ù†Ø¨Ø¶ ØŒ Ø´Ø¨Ù‡Ø§ÛŒ ØŒ ØºÙ†Ú†Ù‡ Ù‡Ø§ ØŒ Ø´Ú©ÙˆÙ‡ ØŒ Ù‡Ù…ÛŒÙ† Ø§Ù…Ø±ÙˆØ² ØŒ Ø¹Ø§Ø¯Øª Øª'`

I always thought that was just a problem related to phpmyadmin since on my application all of them were displayed correctly. 
Now I'm exporting this database and in my mysql dump I see exactly the  characters above so seems that they are stored in this way on the database.

There is an easy way to dump the utf8 characters?

I already tried to follow those suggestion: [I need help fixing Broken UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding)

but the only thing that let visualize the characters properly is print them on a web page and add on top:

```
<html>      
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>         
<body>
```

The collation of the fields is utf8_unicode_ci.
The connection exploit:

`$options = array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',);`

#### Edit: @Álvaro-González Attemp to retrieve hexadecimal values

I enter in the database the symbol `€` then from phpmyadmin I select with: `` SELECT name, HEX(name) as hex_name FROM `items` `` 
that's the result:

name    â‚¬
hex_name    C3A2E2809AC2AC

I will provide any further information on request
Thanks

Comment: it's probably [klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language) ISO 639-2

Comment: Its not very gentle to downvote an answer because you omit the information in your question...

Comment: So... Is your data really broken? You can insert a known character like `€` aka 'EURO SIGN' (U+20AC) and find out if it's correctly encoded as 0xE2 0x82 0xAC (e282ac). In MySQL you have HEX() and in PHP you have bin2hex().

Comment: I didn't do it, I don't  have enough reputation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You wanted `€`?  But the hex is `C3A2E2809AC2AC`.  That is a case of "double encoding" - when you stored the data.

See [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) , especially in the discussion about "double encoding".

The data is broken.  You may be able to fix the data with a messy `UPDATE`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#example_of_double_encoding .

**Edit**

Your original stuff looks like

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('Ù…ÛŒØ«Ù… Ø§Ø¨' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)میثم اب   -- mojibake to ut8,
```