# Displaying special german characters which are stored database using utf _general_ci encode into html page

Tags: html, web-applications

I am writing a web application where I have to display some german special characters like `ä,ü,ö`.

I am using `utf_general_ci` encode in mysql to store the data. So, the special characters like `Ü` is stored as `Ã¼`, hence when I fetch the data that contains a character like `Ü` is displayed as `Ã¼`. which encoding should be used in html to display the german characters properly in html page?

I have used UTF-8 encoding as well as iso-8859-1 both does not seem to work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: UTF-8 is correct. You also need to set the database connection's encoding to UTF-8, that is the most common reason for the thing happening that you describe

Comment: but there is no option of UTF-8 in database settings

Comment: No, the connection itself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application

Comment: ok thank you I will try that

Comment: I already have few data in database which are utf_general_ci encoded for german letters ex. (Ã¼ for Ü) can't this data be converted back to Ü in html ??

Comment: So you fixed the connection and the characters are in there the wrong way? You can see it wrong when viewing the database through phpmyadmin and similar?

Comment: The main problem is I already have few data that were  utf_general_ci  encoded these data is still displayed like Ã¼ for Ü in my html page. Using UTF-8 new set of data is stored properly but the problem is with the old data

Comment: Yeah, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/i-need-help-fixing-broken-utf8-encoding

Comment: Often, a manual `REPLACE()` operation in the database is the easiest way to go, especially when the range of affected characters is from one alphabet only (ÄäÖöÜüß for German e.g. and maybe the occasional á é í)

Comment: thanks a lot for the comments..:) I will check with the replace function

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was, the data in database are saved using charset = latin1 and collation = latin1_german2_ci hence ü was encoded as Ã¼, so in the web application framework I was using i just added these two lines

```
'charset'   => 'latin1',
'collation' => 'latin1_german2_ci',
```

and it worked. Just as a side note when the web application is encoding the data in using 'charset' => 'utf8' and 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci' and some data is already present in the database which has used charset=latin1 and collation=latin1_german2_ci. This may create problem when you try to fetch data using php scripts because of two different encoding present.