# php preg_split doesn't recognise spaces

Tags: php, mysql, string, parsing, preg-split

I copy & paste football games from Betfair e.g. "Bournemouth v Tottenham" and this is stored in a MySQL database. However, when I try:

```
preg_split('/\s+/',  $row['match']);
```

As suggested on here previously it doesn't split on the first space (my ultimate goal would be something like'/\s[v]\s/'). 
When I manually overwrite the field in the database as " v " it then splits it correctly. What could it be treating this character as that appears as a space both in the browser and in PHPMyAdmin but doesn't parse as one? I've tried   but no luck. An example string is:

> Barcelona v Man City - Wednesday 19:45

with this parsing: http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=107841
It doesn't split string until the "Man City" space rather than the " v ". The first one works as I manually replaced the problem chars with spaces in the database

Comment: Try `preg_split('/\s+/u',  $row['match']);`. Also, there may be other non-printable  chars that may prevent the string from splitting.

Comment: Doesn't do anything different. How to find out the non-printables and accomodate for them?

Comment: Copy the value from the DB into http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ Convert field, and click *Convert*. Check for wierd additional codes you get.

Comment: Nothing jumps out. UTF8 encoding of database spaces and hitting spacebar are the same...presumably my copy/paste motion fixes it

Comment: I clicked convert. They don't appear below in the UTF section etc until you do. I also clicked individual convert buttons below but still nothing appearing

Comment: Example string & parsing output added

Comment: Ok, I see it contains no weird characters. However, [this snippet](https://ideone.com/5dY95z) proves there is no issue. There must be something *before* this line of code that modifies it, or the string does not really look like you showed.

Comment: OK. HEX() shows "aÂ vÂ Man C" in the database rather than "a v Man C"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1348521/3832970

Comment: Thanks. I needed to set the character set for some reason (although querying the database says UTF8, when php queries it it says latin1). Doesn't let me mark your comment as correct

Answer (score 1):

Although the database says UTF8 characterset when PHP asks it says latin1. Solution was:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");
```