# Encoding not saved properly to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems with encoding saved incorrectly in the database, so my strings that I was saving to MySQL db are broken now.

Example:

1)
In the database it is saved like:
`HÂ²Flowâ„¢`

But it should be:
`H²FLOW™`

2)

In the database it is saved like:

`Ã†gir Homme`

But it should be:
`ÆGIR Homme`

Does anyone have some suggestions on how can I fix the existing records? I have over 10000 records that have these problems, so I would like to avoid manual editing.

The encoding in my database table is `utf8` and collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

I am using PHP, and any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @ADyson No, it actually doesn't. I need to find a way how to convert existing broken strings into the correct strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing broken UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344692/fixing-broken-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Set your database character set to utf8mb4 encoding.

[MySQL's explanation for charset utf8mb4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Comment: I have updated the table encoding, but didn't fix the problem. `ALTER TABLE my_table_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;` The records are still broken in the DB.