# Weird result at selecting rows

Tags: mysql

I've been worndering why this query returns this result:

```
SELECT direccion_principal
FROM tb_dysport_contacto_medico_terapeutica
WHERE direccion_principal LIKE '%Ãš%'
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+
| direccion_principal |
+---------------------+
| COLSANITAS          |
+---------------------+
```

The table collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your query:

```
LIKE '%Ãš%'
```

is attempting to select results with accented characters. The utf8_general_ci collation removes accents: [What are the diffrences between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Answer (score 2):

Before a query, indicate what charset the client will use to send SQL statements to the server with:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT direccion_principal
FROM tb_dysport_contacto_medico_terapeutica
WHERE direccion_principal LIKE '%Ãš%' collate utf8_bin
```

But this also makes it case sensitive.