# C# and Swedish characters

Tags: c#, mysql, string, encoding

I am trying to save this Swedish string `"120918_demo_öar.jpg"` to MySQL database. Strangely, the value that is getting stored in the database is `"120918_demo_o¨ar.jpg"`

Initially, I thought this was a MySQL issue, but found out that that was not the case.

In code, I get this string `"120918_demo_öar.jpg"` by parsing XML stored in an SQL Server Database table. The string is stored to a variable named imgName

If I do,
`imgName == "120918_demo_öar.jpg"`, it gives false and 
`imgName.Equals("120918_demo_öar.jpg")` also gives false

I have no idea what the issue is. Please help

Thanks in advance
Vivek

Comment: What collation is your database set to use?

Comment: So what do you get if you do `Console.WriteLine(imgName)` after parsing it from the XML file? Are you sure the XML file is using UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @DavidG The collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was wrong to say that I get this by parsing an XML file. The content is being parsed from XML stored in SQL Server table(Specifically, cmsContentXML table of Umbraco). What is strange about this is that some other Swedish text in the same XML file is being written correctly
Sorry for the wrong information about XML

Comment: The value that is stored in database looks like a normalized version of your string. (Some characters are displayed the same way but are different on binary level) Check if imgName.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD).Equals("120918_demo_öar.jpg".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)); also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Arie - The code `imgName.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD).Equals("120918_demo_öar.jpg".Normali‌​ze(NormalizationForm.FormKD));` gives true

Comment: then it seems to be a normalization issue. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1036459/891715