# Updating collation of large tables

Tags: mysql, collation

I am working with a couple of legacy applications and I am trying to update all of their database collations to be utf8_unicode_ci. From my [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci), this is my best bet.

I have found a couple of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql) that help with this and it works fine for most of the tables. Note that I am assuming I need to update the database and tables. I can't just update the database collation.

I keep getting a query timeout error when trying to update the collation of large tables. It seems that the timeout is set to 10mins (600 seconds). I have investigated global variables and timeout variables, but I haven't managed to get anything working. I can't seem to find the correct variable to update so I can make this update.

See error below

`Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

How should I go about getting this updated to work this? Is there a way that I can speed up this whole process of updating the collations?

Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple ways to change `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`; many are wrong.  Would you like to discuss that, too?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured this out. I am using mysqlworkbench which has a DBMS connection keep-alive timeout of 600 seconds. Changing that should sort out my problem.