# DB encoding mistake when i'm looking for a record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm on ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0.

For a project i have a table calles 'Character' where each record is a character. When i'm doing a search for a record with 'where' for example the framework do a mistake between character.

For example :

```
Basic.where(:character => 'Í')
```

return all record with a I like character: "Ï",  character: "I", character: "i", character: "í", character: "ì",...

My DB is encoding in utf8-general-ci and when i put my data into the db I use 'iso-8859-1:utf-8' encoding.

Comment: i  think there is a probability of name clash...because both you table name and attribute name is same...try changing it and reply...

Comment: I try it. Problem not resolved

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_general_ci` has issue were it strip characters with combining characters. In short use `utf8_unicode_ci` which uses the Unicode Collation Algorithm and instead. This has already been answered very well in [What are the diffrences between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

EDIT: 
It actually seems like not even `utf8_unicode_ci` handles this correctly.

Here's the code I used to test this

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_bin';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 0

SET collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 1

SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 1

SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_bin';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 0

SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 1

SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
SELECT 'Ï' = 'I'; -- 1
```

EDIT2:

It looks like Postgres handles this better, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/797. If you can control the choice of DB I would suggest using Postgres instead