# mySQL select í returns results with i

Tags: mysql

I have a table set up where fields are `TEXT utf8_general_ci`.

The field data is set to `Jovíkhan` (where the í is actually ALT-161).

I do a search for `Jovikhan` (regular i, NOT ALT-161), I'm returned all the results as if I had actually used the ALT-161 í.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = 'Jovikhan';
```

Driving me a little bonkers here...  I'm getting this issue directly in phpMyAdmin currently...  why would it return those fields, especially if I'm using `= 'Jovikhan'` vs. `LIKE '%Jov%'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the diffrences between utf8\_general\_ci and utf8\_unicode\_ci?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql).

Answer (score 2):

The `_ci` in `utf_general_ci` means case-insensitive. This causes MySQL to treat `i` and `í` as identical. You need to add `COLLATE utf8_bin` to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = 'Jovikhan' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

For more discussion, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/501151/2057919).

Comment: Why do you refer to another thread which is basically the same question as OP's, and the same answer as yours? Please close as duplicate instead.

Comment: @GolezTrol I felt the first part of the accepted answer on that question could be stated more clearly. I am, however, voting to close as well.

Comment: Thank you very much...  I did do a search but didn't really see anything stand out... maybe you shouldn't mark as duplicate as someone might find this useful.