# Polish and German accented letters in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I want to store in unique column polish and german signs. 
When i alter database:

```
alter database osa character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

I have a problem with german signs.

```
sql> insert into company(uuid, name) VALUE ("1","IDE")
[2016-11-27 10:37:35] 1 row affected in 13ms

sql> insert into company(uuid, name) VALUE ("2","IDĘ")
[2016-11-27 10:37:37] 1 row affected in 9ms

sql> insert into company(uuid, name) VALUE ("3","Schuring")
[2016-11-27 10:37:38] 1 row affected in 13ms

sql> insert into company(uuid, name) VALUE ("4","Schüring")
[2016-11-27 10:37:39] [23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'Schüring' for key 'UK_niu8sfil2gxywcru9ah3r4ec5'
```

Which collate I have to use?

**Edit:**

Also not works for utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter database osa character set utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Works for me. @Maciek Bryński thank you for your hint.

Comment: The `bin` did it, not the `mb4`.

Comment: @RickJames exactly. I know.

Comment: Just clarifying it for others.

Answer (score 2):

The `_ci` in the `COLLATION` indicates "character insensitive".  Unfortunately, it also means "accent insensitive".  So to get `E` and `Ę` to be treated differently, you need a `_bin` collation -- either `utf8_bin` or `utf8mb4_bin`.

`mb4` is needed for Emoji and Chinese, plus some obscure things.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all occurrences of `utf8_general_ci` with `utf8_unicode_ci` instead. `utf8_general_ci` is broken, apparently: [What are the diffrences between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036454/what-are-the-diffrences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

> `utf8_general_ci` is a very simple — and on Unicode, very broken — collation, one that gives incorrect results on general Unicode text.

Comment: Technically speaking, ut8_unicode_ci is broken, fixed by utf8_unicode_520_ci.  With 8.0, there is an even newer standard:  utf8mb4_unicode_900_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try utf8mb4_unicode_ci ?

Utf8 charset cannot store all utf8 characters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: sql> insert into company(name) VALUE ("IDE")
[2016-11-27 22:45:22] 1 row affected in 13ms
sql> insert into company(name) VALUE ("IDĘ")
[2016-11-27 22:45:24] [23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'IDĘ' for key 'UK_name'

Comment: All European characters are covered in both character sets.