# MySQL collation for all languages

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm currently developing a website that is going to show stuff for almost any language in the world. And I'm having problems choosing the best collation to define in the MySQL.

Which one is the best to support all characters? Or the most accurate?

Or is just best to convert all characters to unicode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I generally use 8-bit UCS/Unicode transformation format which works perfect for any (well most) languages

```
utf8_general_ci
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: I'd like to suggest using utf8_unicode_ci instead of utf8_general_ci. For more information about why unicode is better than general @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer is wrong (maybe it was right in 2009).

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is the best encoding to use for wide language support.

**Reasoning and supporting evidence:**

> You want to use `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8` because the latter only supports 3 byte characters, and you want to support 4 byte characters. [(ref)](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434)

and

> You want to use `unicode` rather than `general` because the latter never sorted correctly. [(ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci/766996#766996)

Comment: Thanks! But what is the disadvantage of doing this by default for every db / table?

Does it use more space or will it make my queries / searching inefficient compared to using the default mysql setting (latin1 i guess)

Answer (score 0):

Use **utf8mb4** instead of utf8

```
utf8mb4_general_ci => support 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes
```

and

```
utf8_general_ci or utf8mb3_general_ci => support 1, 2 or 3 bytes
```

It will take space on ur disk as required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or utf8mb4_general_ci can be tricky and cause unexpected behaviors.

Be aware.

Perhaps `utf8mb4_unicode_bin` can be a good option if you want to avoid cases like this one below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### From mysql web site :

utf8mb4: A UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to four bytes per character.

utf8mb3: A UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to three bytes per character. This character set is deprecated in MySQL 8.0, and you should use utfmb4 instead.

### utf8: An alias for utf8mb3. In MySQL 8.0, this alias is deprecated; use utf8mb4 instead. utf8 is expected in a future release to become an alias for utf8mb4.

So prefer to use utf8mb4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).