# utf8_unicode_ci vs utf8_general_ci collation differences?

Tags: mysql, database, types, collation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

What's the difference between the two types of column/table collations? Which is preferred and why? Any thoughts?