# Which of utf8 collations is the best?

Tags: mysql, collation

I want a UTF8 collation for supporting:

- English
- Persian
- Arabic
- French
- Japanese
- Chinese

Does `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` support all these Languages?

Comment: -1 There is no one best answer!  'Collation' is sorting, not collecting.  Each of these languages must be sorted appropriately for that language.  While there might be several ways to sort French for example, the sorting of French is not better than the sorting of Chinese.  It's like which is better an apple or an orange?  There is no best answer to that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set, which supports pretty much every language in the world.

I think the only difference comes with sorting your results, different letters might come in a different order in other languages (accents, umlauts, etc.). Also, comparing `a` to `ä` might behave differently in another collation.

The `_ci` suffix means sorting and comparison happens *c*ase *i*nsensitive.

http://www.collation-charts.org/ might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy :)
one more question : 
you mean if i select utf8_general collation,then it will be a problem to sort my records both in English and Persian or other Langs?

Comment: english and french should sort pretty much the same, i don't know about the other ones  (persian, arabic, japanese, chinese), because they don't use the normal english characters. how do you like them to sort? after english letters, inbetween, before? know what i mean?

Comment: no,i mean to sort persian chars in its way.
it means the same way as sorting english alphabets like A,B,C,...
is it gonna work wrong with this collation?

Comment: collations can be changed after database/table creation, so it shouldn't really be a problem to select a different one if the sorting goes wrong. but i guess it will work the way you intend it to

Comment: @knittl: *collation*  is **always** about sorting. so your answer is a bit by-passing the question which is a pitty as the question is well found in google ... :/

Comment: @hakre: the question is about which collation supports all of the given languages. My answer also states that sorting behaves differently depending on the collation. What are you missing specifically in my answer?

Comment: To make clear why the decision of that one is best for the languages given in question. It's not clear from your answer which first talks about encoding albeit the question is about collation.

Comment: "The _ci suffix means sorting and comparison happens case insensitive." Thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 8):

As `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` was a good decision some time ago. It has some drawbacks now.

MySQL's UTF8 actually uses 3 bytes instead of 4, which you need for symbols like emojis and new asian chars.

So MySQL has a newer charset called **utf8mb4** which actually complies with UTF8 definition.

**To be able fully support Asian languages you will need to choose utf8mb4.**

If you care about correct sorting in multiple languages, use `utf8mb4_unicode` or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead general.

A more detailed answer you can find in [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)