# how to ensure comparison is case sensitive?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to do a comparison in MYSQL but wish for it to be case sensitive

ex:

```
$userID="test"
$q = db_query("select * from users where user_id = '" .  $userID  . "'");
```

In DB:

```
userid = "TEST"
```

Ho do i go about making sure the mysql query does not return TRUE for this query as the userid varialbe doesnt match the case of the userid in the database

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [case insensitive for sql LIKE wildcard statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL manual explains [possible solutions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) quite well.

Comment: You could and should at least still give a quick explanation on the solution

Answer (score 3):

You can force to compare with case sensitivity using COLLATE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

You can also use BINARY

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY user_id = '%John%'`