# not case sensitive query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need to query my database and find results  :

```
mysql_query("select * from ".ALU_TABLE." where username like '%$q%' or name like '%$q%'");
```

if i have a name in my table such as  Book  and i enter book in search box  it wont show the Book

i need to query my database as not to be case sensitive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [case insensitive for sql LIKE wildcard statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+case+insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `LOWER()` function

```
... WHERE LOWER(username) LIKE blabl OR LOWER(name) LIKE asdasd
```

Comment: This works.  But you will not allow the db to use indexes if you mention the column names as parameters to LOWER(), so it might be quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to append something like `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` to your query. (The `_ci` suffix stands for case insensitive.)

Have a look at the documentation: [9.1.7.1. Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html):

> With the COLLATE clause, you can override whatever the default collation is for a comparison. COLLATE may be used in various parts of SQL statements.

Comment: Your database may already be set up for case-insensitive collation.