# case-insensitive search of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

case-insensitive search of MySQL?

For my site search, what is the most efficient way of to query my db for a word/phrase regardless of case?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028839/not-case-sensitive-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your database / table is not set up with a case-insensitive collate you need to append something like `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` to your query. (The `_ci` suffix stands for case insensitive.)

Have a look at the documentation: [9.1.7.1. Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html):

> With the COLLATE clause, you can override whatever the default collation is for a comparison. COLLATE may be used in various parts of SQL statements.