# Case Sensitive Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive, exact-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql case sensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query)

'm working on an PHP script that checks some values to the ones in the database. So far I thought it worked right, but I found an problem.

The query isn't looking for the specific characters.

So if I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `facilitydb_login`
WHERE
facilitydb_login.`password` = 'PASS'
```

I want the result, because the password is PASS. But if you fill in pass (lowercase) the same entry is returned.

How can I make it case sensitive?

Comment: Is the `collation` for the column case sensitive? What database server are you using? If it's MySql (as you mention PHP so it's a fairly common combination) you can use COLLATE - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: yes, i'm using MySQL. @dash, i don't know, how can i see that?

Comment: @TWCrap Execute `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM db.table` where `db` and `table` are replaced with your database and table names

Comment: You can also use the `binary` keyword. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use case sensitive collation, for example

```
SELECT *
FROM `facilitydb_login`
WHERE facilitydb_login.`password` collate latin1_general_cs = 'PASS'
```

CS in the name means that it's Case Sensitive

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I will mark your answer in 7 minuts ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you could make the column case sensitive

Assume you are using mysql database

```
ALTER TABLE facilitydb_login 
CHANGE password `password` VARCHAR(100) BINARY NOT NULL;
```

or If you want to make part of the select statement then

```
SELECT *
FROM `facilitydb_login`
WHERE BINARY 
facilitydb_login.`password` = 'PASS'
```