# php mysql query select match exact word

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the match exact word from table, but i got a problem that

if row like : Angel and i did select * from table where row = "angel" it success and first

letter is small and in db its capital,

```
$r = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ID 
                                  FROM Login
                                  WHERE Username = 'angel'
                                    And Password = 'zxc'"));
if($r[0])
    die("success");
else
    die("failed");

In mysql Table
Username : varchar(50) : Angel
Password varchar(50) : zxc
```

results should be falied

because its Angel not angel

so any solution for it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BINARY` for that.

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE BINARY `row` = 'angel'
```

That will make a case sensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is due to the collation of your table field. you should set it to a case sensitive collation usually suffixed with `cs` like `latin1_swedish_cs`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$r = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Login WHERE  
            Password = 'zxc' AND Username collate latin1_general_cs = 'angel'"));
```

Read [Case Sensitive Database Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973682/case-sensitive-database-query) and [MySQL case sensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT ID
FROM Login
WHERE Username = 'angel' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("
    ALTER TABLE `Login`
    CHANGE `Username` `Username` VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL
");    

$r = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM Login WHERE  Username = 'angel' And Password = 'zxc'"));
if($r[0])
    die("success");
else
    die("failed");
```

Now it will work.

Comment: How would you know in which case the username is stored in DB? it wont always be `ucfirst`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT ID
FROM Login
WHERE upper(Username) = upper('angel')
```