# Is data stored in tables case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have three table samples. I have used `mysql` to store data in database

```
+--------------------------+
| Table-1                  |
+--------------------------+
| Sl.No | Name | City      |
+-------+------+-----------+
|  1    | Carl | Australia |
+-------+------+-----------+

+--------------------------+
| Table-1                  |
+--------------------------+
| Sl.No | Name | City      |
+-------+------+-----------+
|  1    | carl | australia |
+-------+------+-----------+

+--------------------------+
| Table-1                  |
+--------------------------+
| Sl.No | Name | City      |
+-------+------+-----------+
|  1    | CARL | AUSTRALIA |
+-------+------+-----------+
```

- clearly we can see one row of data in each table
- nature of data is same

what I have done is I have used different case letters some are uppercase letters and some are lowercase letters.

Are data stored in database case sensitive?

Comment: "case-sensitive" for what purpose?  The stored data is just data.  It's not interpreted as anything, not executed as code, it's just raw data.  Whatever you *do* with that data may or may not be case-sensitive.  At a raw data level, the binary representation of "Carl" and "CARL" are different, so the data is different.  But whatever uses that data may not care about that difference.

Comment: Data is stored the way it was entered (caps, lower case, mix), but MyQL SQL select statements are case insensitive by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, the database stores the data how you submit it.

if you say:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (LowerCase, UpperCase) VALUES ("abcd", "ABCD");
```

it will insert:

```
LowerCase | UpperCase
abcd      | ABCD
```

if you do

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (LowerCase, UpperCase) VALUES ("AbCd", "aBcD");
```

it will insert:

```
LowerCase | UpperCase
AbCd      | aBcD
```

it's up to you to sanitize the inputs to the case you want, or just let it go as entered.

however, when I do a

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LowerCase="abcd";
```

it will return both entries.

Answer (score 6):

Data is just stored as raw data. However if you want to get the data in any particular format you can format it. You may insert the data as per your convinience however internally they are interpreted the same ie, `ABC is same as abc and aBc`

**By default MySQL queries are not case-sensitive.**

From the [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database and table names. **This means
>   database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS
>   X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that
>   is not case sensitive. However, Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes,
>   which are case sensitive just as on any Unix.**

## On a side note:-

***Inside the database, all data is stored in binary format. You can have different data types which is used by the computer to interpret how to show the data to the user, but that is just a mask.***