# I need exact character match in PHP

Tags: php, regex, mysqli, preg-match, character

I am trying to make a script, that interact with mysql database and allows to find someone by username. But the problem is that it is not comparing characters. Means in my databse, user name is "abcd", in lowercase. But when I go to

localhost/ABCD or
localhost/Abcd or
localhost/ABcd or any upper or lowercase, it shows me same result. I want different result with different cases. I don't know what to use. I searched a lot and found preg_match function but don't know how to use. The function I created for this match from database is,

```
function CheckPnP($var){
    $db = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

    if($var){
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  `view` WHERE `username` =  '$var'")){
            if($result->num_rows){
                $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();     
                $_GET['username'] = $rows['username'];
                $_GET['view'] = $rows['page'];  
                include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/view.php';
                return true;
            }       
        }   
    }       
}
```

and my view.php page codes are

```
<?php
@$view = $_GET['view'];
@$username = $_GET['username'];

if($view == 'profile'){
    echo 'This is profile page.';

    }
 else if ($view == 'page'){
    echo 'This is page.';
    }
else if ($view){
    header('Location: /');
    }   
else if (empty($view)){
    echo 'this is view page123. ';
}

echo '<br>'.$username;
```

?>

view.php page's codes are temporary. I will change them soon but right now I need to match characters of username from database and I need exact character match.

Please help me.

Comment: So he problem is that your MySQL query is not case sensitive ?
You might find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, but I want to ask that is there any other method that I can use in PHP to match characters?

Comment: where do you want this PHP comparison ?

Comment: I want to learn it, so I can use it in my other scripts. Can you suggest me where should I use PHP method?

Comment: well what do you want exactly ? For example, do you want to test that the variable $var is all lowercase ?

Comment: Leave it @Matthew, I got it. I will use BINARY which you suggested me first. I think it will be helpful... :D thanks anyways... :D

Comment: you can use strcmp ( ) method to compare the string in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found out about this a few weeks ago:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE BINARY `your_column` = 'VaLue';
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE BINARY `your_column` = 'value';
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE BINARY `your_column` = 'vaLue';
```

This would return different results depending on your query.

I suggest you do the above instead of in PHP.

About your second question:

There are a ton of things you can do to match characters in PHP. `strcmp` (case sensitive), `===`, `==`, `strcasecmp` (case insenstive)