# How to make case sensitive log in with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, case-sensitive

Why my login code not case sensitive?, How can I do?

My table "member"

```
 _________________________
|__username__|__password__| 
|____mango___|___123456___|
```

I try to login with

```
1. username = mango and password = 123456 , it's echo "true"
2. username = MANGO and password = 123456 , it's echo "true"
3. username = Mango and password = 123456 , it's echo "true"
```

Why my login code not case sensitive ?, how can i do ?

```
<?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    $strUsername = trim($_POST["usename"]);
    $strPassword = trim($_POST["password"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($strUsername)."' 
            and password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($strPassword)."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1)
       {
           echo "true";
       }  
    else
       {
           echo "false";
       }        
?>
```

Comment: A little-searching should have brought [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7857705/2513523) up

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) (i.e. none!) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: key success is `BINARY` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [binary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE BINARY `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($strUsername)."' 
        AND BINARY `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($strPassword)."' ";
```

There are also a few other improvements you could make to your code.

1. You aren't using any hashing for your password - [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)
2. You are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions which PHP are trying to phase out. There are good alternatives out there, [this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) gives a good explanation which should help you choose which alternative would be best for you.