# .htaccess or php case sensitive URLs

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have been googling and stackoverflowing, but I couldn't seem to find any answer as people have the exact opposite problem. I have .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?tag=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^w/([^/]+)?$ w.php?post=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And php code:

```
$unique = $_GET["post"];
```

followed by a mySQL query and more php code. The problem I am facing here is that no matter if I use *.com/w/AAAAAA or *.com/w/aaaaaa, the outcome is the same. The script will find AAAAAA in the database and display the post. Is there a way of making all this case sensitive?

Comment: You need to narrow down your problem, are you sure it is related to the url or is it perhaps related to the database itself?

Comment: That is probably the problem, I am unable to identify the source. I have been researching mysql case-sensitivity of tables, but I can only find documentation related to various servers and os.

Comment: mysql is case insensitive, UNLESS you force a `binary` comparison or are using a non-case-sensitive collation in your tables/fields.

Comment: Yes, these comments are correct. The issue is that mysql is case insensitive - have a look here for the correct way to query with case sensitivity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7857705/844726

Comment: @swatkins this totally worked! Thank you!