# How can I get case sensitive from getting data in mysql? my language is php

Tags: php

How can I get case sensitive from getting data in mysql? my language is php hypertext preprocessor.

I would like to get the **`"user1"`** (without qoutation):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = 'user1'
```

This is my query but I would like to get the exact username from the database in case sensitive.

Comment: So any problem when you run this Query?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query

Answer (score 0):

MySql will, by default, perform a case-insensitive search but you can use the BINARY operator to make this case sensitive.

try:-

```
select * from `user` where binary `Username`='user1';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try as this ...

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE BINARY  `Username` = 'user1'
```