# Django - Query EXACT string match

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have a user in my DB with this value:

```
booking_id -> 25DgW
```

This field is marked as `unique` in my model

```
booking_id = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=5, default=set_booking_id)
```

But now when I query for the user like this:

```
>>> User.objects.get(booking_id='25dgw')  # I think this should throw a DoesNotExist exacption
<User: John Doe>
```

Even if I do:

```
>>> Partner.objects.get(booking_id__exact='25dgw')
<User: John Doe>
```

I need a query that return the user only if the code is written exactly in the same way than is saved in database: `25DgW` instead of `25dgw`.

How should I query?

Comment: Just in case you are not sure, this is the mysql issue. It's not that easy to achieve this using ORM. Raw sql might do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query

Comment: @ShangWang So what is `__exact` for? Is there any way (hard and not easy) to do this?

Comment: Change your mysql collation to a case sensitive one. `__exact` means that Django should tell the database that you want exact matches. Database collation sets whether the database should consider 'bob' and 'Bob' exact matches. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql shows some ways to do this, but it's kind of a big topic.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I have been looking at my schema an I found that it uses `latin1` collation, but `latin1_general_cs` is available, is it possible to change?

Comment: I think `__exact` and `=` are the same thing.

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-database for the sql commands to do this. And, yes, `__exact` is the default, so `filter(foo='bar')` and `filter(foo__exact='bar')` are equivalent.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I did it, now I am using latin1_general_cs collation, ORM is still having the same behavior, Is there something else that I should try?

Comment: Check what happens if you run the select manually - depending on what you changed, it may not have had the desired effect. For instance, I believe changing the database collation changes the default collation for new tables, but does not affect existing tables.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You're right. I have just changed the collation for this table and now it's workig as desired. Thanks dude, please consider give this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MySQL does not consider the case of the strings. There will be a character set and collation associated with the database/table or column.

The default collation for character set latin1, which is latin1_swedish_ci, which is case-insensitive. You will have to change the collation type to `latin1_general_cs` which supports case sensitive comparison.

You can to change character-set/collation settings at the database/table/column levels.

The following steps worked for me.

1. Go to MySQL shell

   `mysql -u user -p databasename`
2. Change character set and collation type of the table/column

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
   ```
3. Now try the query

   ```
   Partner.objects.get(booking_id__exact='25dgw')
   ```

This throws an error, `table matching query does not exist.`

Reference - [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html)

Answer (score 2):

`User.objects.filter(booking_id='25dgw', booking_id__contains='25dgw').first()`
seems to work for me (result = None). The `booking_id` parameter is to assert the correct letters and no more, the `booking_id__contains` to assert the case sensitiveness.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
qs.filter(booking_id__contains='25DgW').first()
```