# How to find a specfic string in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have a `sender field`. In that fields contain some set of rows like..

```
sender
----
Rubin
RUBIN
```

But i can select rubin.
query:

```
select * from request where sender='rubin'
```

This query output is:

```
Rubin
RUBIN
```

I need output is, query returns null value:

```
returns null value
```

Comment: Seems like you're using a case-insensitive collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE CAST(sender_id AS BINARY) RLIKE '^rubin$';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use binary for that column,

```
select * from request where BINARY sender='rubin'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the SQL "LIKE" key word,

for example:

```
select * from request where sender LIKE '%rubin%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix, you should use a BINARY of value.

```
select * from request where sender = BINARY 'rubin'
```

[Refrerence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is; by default mysql will create columns that are not case sensitive. You need to specify whether a column is case sensitive while creating the table. The `BINARY` text can be added to any column you need to be case sensitive.
So in your example. If you create the table like this

```
CREATE TABLE request
('id' int, 'sender' varchar(7) BINARY)
```

and then ran the query you used, it will return nulll

Running the query like Gulmuhammad and Mayank mentioned in their answer will also work.