# MySQL: Set case sensitive as default

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL on Windows 10.

Is there any way to set case sensitive as default?

To have case sensitivity in any query, whether it's column name or value name.

Comment: Column names are never case sensitive on any platform. Values (if you mean that by value names) depend on the definition of your column (e.g. binary would use case sensitive comparison). You can make tablenames (and some other objects) case sensitive, but it is very discouraged on windows (because you can still not have two tables with the same name and might result in some problems). Maybe you should elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really knows about `case sensitive` that you meaning above

But I though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857705/8190366) help you out