# Codeigniter database make case sensitive

Tags: database, codeigniter, case, case-sensitive

I need to consider case sensitivity when login to my system.  But password do not consider case.

```
    $this->db->select('user.*,userprofile.*,user.id as uid');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('userprofile', 'userprofile.id = user.id');
    $this->db->like('email', $udata['email']);
    $this->db->like('password', $udata["password"]);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

The above is my query. How can I change it so that its case sensitive?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with the password field to make it case sensitive unless you are storing passwords in plain text, which you __really__ should not be doing!  By using a hash function, the input you provide will provide a hash which will be completely different if the case is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changes my variables names to get the two separately and used LIKE inside 'where'.

I changes this :

```
$this->db->like('password', $udata["password"]);
```

to

```
$this->db->where('password LIKE binary', $password);
```

Answer (score 1):

a possible approach could be

```
$this->db
    ->select('user.*,userprofile.*,user.id as uid')
    ->from('user')
    ->join('userprofile', 'userprofile.id = user.id')
    ->where('email', $udata['email'])
    ->where('BINARY password =', $this->db->escape($udata["password"]), false)
    ->get();
```

> For more information take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query)