# Spring data JPA with MySQL server: case is ignored on Entity class by default

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id;

  @NotNull
  @NaturalId
  private String tagId;

  @NotNull
  @Size(max = 255, message = "Employee name can not be longer than 255 character")
  private String name;

  @Type(type = "yes_no")
  private boolean isInside;

  @PastOrPresent(message = "Last RFID timestamp can not be in the future")
  private ZonedDateTime lastSwipe;

  //Constuctors, getters and setters
}
```

With the following JpaRepository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

  Optional<Employee> findByTagId(String tagId);

}
```

**Let's say I have an employee in the database, with tagId "SomeStringForID".
Right now, if I query the database using the `findByTagId` method where tagId equals "sOmEStringforid" for example, the employee is found in the database**. If I try to save another employee with tagId "sOmEStringforid", I will get an exception, thanks to the `@NaturalId` annotation.

Any idea what causes this behaviour? Spring named queries have options for IgnoreCase, so I'm pretty sure this should not be the default behaviour. I checked one of my older projects too, where to my surprise I have found the same behaviour. I tried both JDK 8 and 11 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is not case sensitive. You can query for a record using a value of 'a' and it can return a record 'A' or 'a'.

See the following:

[MySQL case insensitive select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select)

[MySQL case sensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857669/mysql-case-sensitive-query/36768933)

[How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Comment: oh, I didn't even think that is a possibility. TIL

Comment: btw for anyone reading: the solution is to make sure you use a case sensitive collaction when creating the database schema.