# Can't make a partial match from TextBox in a query

Tags: sql, ado.net

I have a column with data like this "Tom Hardy" and I add a new query to search in this column like this :

```
SELECT  Number, Name, Business, [Tax File No], Phone
FROM            Archive
WHERE        (Name = @Name)
```

and it works when I entered the full name like "Tom Hardy" but I want to find results by searching just "Tom" or "Hardy".

I also tried :

```
SELECT  Number, Name, Business, [Tax File No], Phone
FROM            Archive
WHERE        (Name IN (@Name))
```

Neither work.

Using Visual Studio 2010 with C# and SQL database connected to it.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a wild card to your parameter

```
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
```

So

```
SELECT  Number, Name, Business, [Tax File No], Phone
FROM            Ahrcive
WHERE        (Name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI like '%' + @Name + '%')
```

[I don't think you can do this using the 'in' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause).

Comment: Thank you for your concern but it didn't work. Still can't search a not full name

Comment: @MohammedAhmed Updated again as an alternative to Jorge lower case suggestion (although it may be too localized for your needs). You can also add this to the database if needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement

Comment: +1 for elegance :) .. I don't know why Mohammed keeps having problems though

Comment: Thank you. @MohammedAhmed Are you getting any errors, or just 0 results? Can you try the code above in Sql Server Management Studio instead of in code so we can rule that out.

Comment: @Dave when trying to use your last update it gave me error "Invalid Collation UTF8_GENERAL_CI "

Comment: @ Dave It worked now with you first post all I have to do is change the column type from nchar to nvarchar. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Dave is right, except that mybe you also want to check for lowercase/uppercase escenarios,
maybe that is the reason you are not receiving good results

like :

```
SELECT  Number, Name, Business, [Tax File No], Phone
FROM            Archive
WHERE        (LOWER(Name) like '%' + LOWER(@Name) + '%')
```

this statement converts both values to lowercase and the comparison is valid again

Comment: @MohammedAhmed - Can you please try this in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) so we can rule out any C# / connection / coding issues.