# Case insensitive search (and order by case insensitively) in a case-sensitive column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, utf-8

I have a case-sensitive colume(utf8_bin collation). 
I need to search a string case-insensitively and order the results case-insensitively.

Is have written this query.

```
SELECT customer_name 
   FROM customers
   WHERE CONVERT(customer_name USING UTF8) LIKE 'aB%' 
   ORDER BY CONVERT(customer_name USING UTF8) 
   LIMIT 0,10
```

Is this efficient? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

What about converting in uppercase?

```
SELECT customer_name 
   FROM customers
   WHERE UPPER(customer_name) LIKE 'AB%' 
   ORDER BY UPPER(customer_name) 
   LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Yeah. I had that initially. But I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876802/1137788) that this affects the use of Index. Hence I used Collate.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I didn't know Collate ;)