# Case insensitivity for SQL LIKE when contents is latin1

Tags: mysql, sql, case-insensitive, latin1, mysql-error-1253

I attempted to apply the solution posted on [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement), but I'm given the error

> 1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

**How can I apply case insensitivity to a `latin1` table?**

Comment: try `COLLATE latin1_general_ci` instead - that should work.

Comment: @Dash why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mycolumn = CAST('CamelCaseWord' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76b2/2).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for case-insensitive comparison, why not just force both sides to uppercase?

`` SELECT * FROM trees WHERE upper(trees.`title`) LIKE '%ELM%' ``

Comment: I was under the impression that this only worked on Oracle (we're using MySQL)

Comment: That an unless I'm missing something, not all UTF-8 lowercase letters have a one to one matching with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Supuhstar, you may wish to [consult your manual] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper).

Comment: @Erik, That's interesting.  I've never heard of a letter with more than one uppercase form.  What the standard C function toupper(3) return for one?  Do you have an example?

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden [Phil Haacked - Turkish i Problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx) In short, `'i' == 'I'` is `true` us-en, but `false` in tr-tr.

Comment: Updating that last comment:  In short, `"i".ToUpper() == "I"` is `true` us-en, but `false` in tr-tr.