# ATK4 Quicksearch case-sensitive?

Tags: case-sensitive, atk4, agiletoolkit

I'm using ATK4.2.4, I've got a grid with a QuickSearch but it appears to be case-sensitive. However, looking at the example here: http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/gui/grid it does not behave case-sensitive.

I've tried feeding my grid from a model and directly through setSource, no difference.

Any clues on which direction to look for the cause and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickSearch is case sensitive (class QuickSearch method PostInit).

But in case you use MySQL for your model, then MySQL itself ignores string case for LIKE statements if correctly configured.
See here: [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement)

Comment: Thanks, guess I was looking in the wrong place... Thanks for the link!