# CakePhp, how MySQL "Like" works as case insensitive search

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In CakePhp, how MySQL **Like** works as case insensitive search. 
I have tried with following code but problem is also coming here.

If i am searching "**Motel Park**" then result is fine.

But when searching "**motel park**" no result is found.

In database Collation is  **latin1_swedish_ci**

```
$where_condition = array('Ad.completed' => 1,
                         'Ad.address LIKE '=>'%'.$_REQUEST['address'].'%',
                         'Ad.status' =>$ad_status
                        );
 $result =  $this->Ad->find('all',array('conditions'=>$where_condition));
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be using the `$_REQUEST` superglobal. CakePHP has `$this->request->data` for POST data, and `$this->request->query` for query string parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using "COLLATE utf_general_ci"  collation. refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement).

but there is an easy solution , by converting all string in to lowercase. then check.

```
$request_address=strtolower($_REQUEST['address']);
$where_condition = "Ad.completed =  1 AND
                    LOWER(Ad.address) LIKE '%".$request_address."%' AND
                    Ad.status ='".$ad_status."'";  

$result =  $this->Ad->find('all',array('conditions'=>$where_condition));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert both the value to lowercase to use `LIKE` statement

```
$where_condition = array(
    'Ad.completed' => 1,
   'LOWER(Ad.address) LIKE '=>'%'.strtolower($this->request->data['address']).'%',
    'Ad.status' =>$ad_status
  );
$result =  $this->Ad->find('all',array('conditions'=>$where_condition));
```