# Utf8_bin and uppercase/lowercase search results

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem with using Mysql queries (finding cities) with German letters.

If i typed to autocomplete input city name "Burgen" - the result was "Burgen" and "Bürgen". So You can see, Bürgen don't match Burgen.

So i changed database and tables encoding from ut8_general_ci to utf8_bin.

And now, search works fine, but another problem arises:

Now search result is case sensitive, then i type "burgen" i have no results, but when type "Burgen" - result is correct.

My question is: is there a way to setup database to work with lowercase ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876820/1275307 ?

Comment: ... or `'SELECT LOWER(your_column) ... WHERE your_column = ' . strtolower($your_var);`