# Why doesn't this LIKE query return any results?

Tags: mysql

I made table copied from W3schools 2015 ... Here's some of the data:

[image]

here the columns and data types i used as follows.

```
CustomerID = int
CustomerName = varchar
ContactName = varchar
Address = varchar
City = varchar
PostalCode = varchar
Country = text
```

When i used the following query i got the actual result.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE 'U%';    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE 'M%';    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE 'G%';
```

Now the problem was that When i used the following query, i weren't getting actual result.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE 's%';
```

i didn't see any row !!
But We should have seen the following output,

[image]

why ?? can anybody explain pls...

Moreover I am totally in Novice phase..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Case sensitivity can be a subtle thing in your table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Take a look at your collation and character set. That is, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Customers` and see what you get. It looks like you're using a binary (case-sensitive) collation.

Comment: My Country column collation was   latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: sorry ...Country Column data type was tinytext and charter set =latin1

Answer (score 0):

May be,
This is Because of Your Country Column Starting with 'S'(which we think) are not really Starting with 'S', May be it's first charter is a Space.(Just A Guess)

so, For this Case you can try Once,

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE rtrim(ltrim(Country)) LIKE 's%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE replace(Country,' ','') LIKE 's%';
```

Answer (score -1):

See [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement)

Comment: Is this `mysql`or `sql-server` or `ms-access`, you listed all 3 tags

Comment: sorry for that ..  its will be mysql