# Laravel where like not working properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, sql-like, query-builder

I would like to use the query builder with the LIKE operator but it's not working properly.

Here is my code in my controller :

```
public function listall($query) {
        $Clubs = Club::where('clubs.name', 'like', "%$query%")
                ->Join('leagues', 'clubs.league_id', '=', 'leagues.id')
                ->select('clubs.id', 'clubs.name', 'clubs.blason', 'leagues.name as league_name')
                ->orderBy('clubs.name')
                ->get();

        return Response::json($Clubs);
    }
```

Here is my Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hasard(min,max){
        return min+Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1));
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Set the Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
        var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: "{{ url('club/listall') }}"+'/%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%'
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        $(".club-search").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            source: engine.ttAdapter(),
            display: "name",
            // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
            name: 'clubsList',

            // the key from the array we want to display (name,id,email,etc...)
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Aucun club trouvé.</div></div>'
                ],
                header: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                ],
                suggestion: function (data) {
                    if (data.blason == null) {
                        var aleat = hasard(1,4);
                        if (aleat == 1) {
                            var blason = "/images/blasons/blason-bleu.svg";
                        } else if (aleat == 2) {
                            var blason = "/images/blasons/blason-orange.svg";
                        } else if (aleat == 3) {
                            var blason = "/images/blasons/blason-rouge.svg";
                        } else if (aleat == 4) {
                            var blason = "/images/blasons/blason-vert.svg";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var blason = "/images/blasons/" + data.blason;
                    }
                    return '<a href="{{ url('club') }}' + '/' + data.id + '" class="list-group-item"><span class="row">' +
                                '<span class="avatar">' +
                                    '<img src="{{asset('/')}}' + blason + '">' +
                                "</span>" +
                                '<span class="name">' + data.name + '<br><small style="color:grey;">(Ligue ' + data.league_name + ')</small></span>' +
                            "</span>"
          }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But its not working completely properly... In general, it finds results, but I'll give u an example of a search query. One possible query is "montagnarde". I'll give you the result for every letter. Typing:

```
m --> lot of results
mo --> lot of results
mon --> lot of results
mont --> lot of results
monta --> lot of results
montag --> lot of results
montagn --> lot of results
montagna --> no result
montagnar --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE"
montagnard --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE"
montagnarde --> finds only "J.S. MONTAGNARDE" and "LA MONTAGNARDE"
montagnarde i --> finds only "U.S. MONTAGNARDE INZINZAC"
```

Does anybody see where is the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of using `->get()`at the end of your query, use `->toSql()` and then print or `dd()` the result. This will show you what query is actually being run - useful debugging like you are doing now.

Comment: Here is the result : 
"select `clubs`.`id`, `clubs`.`name`, `clubs`.`blason`, `leagues`.`name` as `league_name` from `clubs` inner join `leagues` on `clubs`.`league_id` = `leagues`.`id` where `clubs`.`name` like ? order by `clubs`.`name` asc"

Answer (score 2):

I think your string concatenation is wrong.

Try to change where statement to

```
where('clubs.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the same result with :
where('clubs.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%') or
where('clubs.name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `"%$query%"`. PHP interpolates variables in double quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$Clubs = Club::where(DB::raw('LOWER(clubs.name)'), 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($query).'%')
->Join('leagues', 'clubs.league_id', '=', 'leagues.id')
->select('clubs.id', 'clubs.name', 'clubs.blason', 'leagues.name as league_name')
->orderBy('clubs.name')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dealeo You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
public function listall($query) {
        $Clubs = Club::Join('leagues', 'clubs.league_id', 'leagues.id')
                ->where('clubs.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->select('clubs.id', 'clubs.name', 'clubs.blason', 'leagues.name as league_name')
                ->orderBy('clubs.name')
                ->get();

        return Response::json($Clubs);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have the same results with your code.

Comment: @Dealeo-JeromeMansbendel I have updated my answer. Would you try this?

Answer (score 0):

check now:

public function listall($query) {

```
dd( $query );

$clubs = Club::join('leagues', 'clubs.league_id', '=', 'leagues.id')
->where('clubs.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
->select('clubs.id', 'clubs.name', 'clubs.blason', 'leagues.name as league_name')
->orderBy('clubs.name');

dd( $clubs->toSql() );

return Response::json($clubs);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use the search-query like this:

```
->where('clubs.name', 'like', "%{$query}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` to your table definition and then try your query like this (with leftJoin):

```
public function listall($query) {
        $Clubs = Club::leftJoin('leagues', 'clubs.league_id', '=', 'leagues.id')
                ->where('clubs.name', 'like', "%$query%")
                ->select('clubs.id', 'clubs.name', 'clubs.blason', 'leagues.name as league_name')
                ->orderBy('clubs.name')
                ->get();

        return Response::json($Clubs);
    }
```

Collate utf8 suggestion from: [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL like statements and "%xyz spaces-bla-bla 123%" doesn't work.
It's not a Laravel problem.