# Read multiple entries with a Where clause

Tags: select, mysqli, where-clause, sql-like

I tried to build a User search function but i ran into a problem a while ago. My function, which looks like this:

```
"Select id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%search%'"
```

Is showing me only the user Janamaris ( userlist is a bit lower )
but as you see jns.drws has also a j in his username ( J = $search ).

So my Problem now i want to show all users with  a J in his/her username

So how can i get all users with WHERE?

My Signed Users are [id, username]

29. Tolkosino

47, Janamaris

48, TheCrazyMan

49, jns.drws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Beispiel einer Foreach Schleife bzw. While Schleife Posten?**

English: Can someone post an example of a `foreach` e.g. `while` loop?

The sql is fine and will get all rows you need:

`"Select id, username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%search%'"`

If you have problems with upper/lower case then read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876820/4916265

Example with `while`

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
 if(is_object($result)){
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo "<div id=\"content-b\">";
     echo "<p class=\"usrsrch\">User ID : " . $row['id'] . "";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<p class=\"usrsrch\">Username : . $row['username'] . "";
     echo "</div>";
   }
  } else {
    echo 'nix gefunden';
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder where the OP went; what you posted should be working for them.

Comment: hm im trying right now... somehow it dosnt work right

Comment: Ok now i get both users but only showed jns.drws i look how i fix that but anyway thanks for your help

Comment: OK guys got this i had to move the div open 2 rows above so the whole while($row .... ) loop is in the div and the div closer also 1 row down.