# SQL SELECT query UPPER in LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5.4

i have a problem in my search form. In my 
**database all data is in upper case**
, so when i input lower case letter in search field it do not gives any result. So i trying to find out how to make my form insensitive.

This is the model:

```
// chassis
    public function chassis($chassis)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('model_type_en', 'LIKE', "%$chassis%");
    }
```

Do you have any ideas how i can use `upper(model_type_en)` in this function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// chassis
    public function chassis($chassis)
    {
        $str = strtoupper($chassis);
        return $this->builder->where('model_type_en', 'LIKE', "%$str%");
    }
```

Comment: It works! Im new in laravel, thank you for your help.