# Spring EL - Syntax for case-insensitive LIKE?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-el

I am trying to implement a repository query method to search an address by its house name. I want this search query to be case-insensitive.

I have the following search method defined in the Address repository. But this search is case sensitive.

```
 @Query(value = "select ad from #{#entityName} ad where ad.houseName LIKE :houseName%")
    public Page<LocalAddress> findByHouseName(@Param("houseName") String houseName, Pageable page);
```

How do I make this query case insensitive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Comment: @DeltaCharlie If my answer helped you please don't forget to accept it )

Answer (score 2):

To implement your task you don't need manually write a query, just use a Spring Data [magic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation):

```
Page<LocalAddress> findByHouseNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String partOfHouseName, Pageable page);
```

This method will use case-insensitive `like` operator and fetch your data independently from DB.

---

Nevertheless, you can specify this explicitly in the JPQL query:

```
@Query("select a from LocalAddress a where upper(a.houseName) like concat('%', upper(?1), '%')")
Page<LocalAddress> getByName(String partOfHouseName, Pageable page)
```

More info here: [JPQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun)

Comment: I am already aware of this method. I was just trying to implement the same with SpEL. With findBy queries names get too long at times so there must be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is rather question of a database engine. SpEL only evaluates the expression and replaces the placeholder with a value. See question [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Comment: So is it not possible to do a case-insensitive search using LIKE in SpEL? I dont want my query to be tied to any specific DB engine

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the wrong tool to do the job. How would you expect Spring to implement the feature? I doubt it's intelligent enough to rewrite your query magically (it would have to support all database vendors).

Comment: I think I understand your point. Since syntax for case-insensitive LIKE is different based on the DB engine, it is not possible to generate a dynamic query using SpEL right?

Comment: Right. It's not impossible, but it's not an easy thing in general.